# Maven test runs local fails in CI environment

Tags: java, maven, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a file `src/test/resources/ConfigTest.json` with my *test* configuration. My maven test helper class (an enum) has the following 2 lines:

```
ClassLoader c = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
File configFile = new File(c.getResource("ConfigTest.json").getFile());
```

When I run `mvn test` from Eclipse or local command line, works as expected. However when run from a Bitbucket pipeline it throws a `NullPointerException` for not finding the file. My `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file:

```
image: maven:3.3.9
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - maven
        script:
          - mvn -B verify
```

I also tried:

- use the class: `this.getClass().getResource("/ConfigTest.json")`
- use the Thread: `ClassLoader c = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`

Full example class:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ClassLoaderTest {

    @Test
    public final void test() {
        ClassLoader c = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        File configFile = new File(c.getResource("ConfigTest.json").getFile());
        Assert.assertTrue(configFile.exists());
    }
}
```

What do I miss? How is the Bitbucket runtime different from my local environment when it comes to resource loading?

**Update** The POM.XML

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>io.projectcastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>io.projectcastle.tjwt2sfoauth</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Authentication using custom JWT</name>
        <description>Translates custom JWT into OAuth session</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: Never access resources as files. Always use `getResourcesAsStream("/ConfigTest.json");` and continue with the stream but not with file!

Comment: Ok. I’ll try that in an hour

Comment: Tried that - same result. Is there something amiss in my POM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mystery solved. The culprint was this line in my `.bash_profile` on my Mac:

```
       # Case-insensitive globbing (used in pathname expansion)
       shopt -s nocaseglob;
```

It allows the `getResourceAsStream(name)` (and any other file operation) find files case insensitive. I presumed that Java on Mac would always be case sensitive.

There was one capitalisation error in my resource name, so the pipeline rightfully failed. Fixed the typo, all is good.

:blush: